# How to use bridge table to filter the required other tables

Tags: powerbi

I have a bridge table for 3 different tables but I cannot add the required columns in table visual from those 3 tables. When I add columns from different tables in visual, the error occurs. Have used bridge table column in table visual too.

Table visual is okay when columns are used from one table connecting with bridge table but when columns from other tables connected to bridge table are added in visual, the visual encounters error and when checking there is message that there is no relationship between the tables.

I have also used bidirectional filters between tables but its not working.

Need help.